# Как сделать так, чтобы при отмене оплаты не создавалася заказ? Woocmerce

Tags: woocommerce, liqpay

Как сделать так, чтобы при отмене оплаты не создавалася заказ?
Возможно как-то заблокировать создание заказа пока не будет успешной оплаты?

Подскажите в какую сторону копать, я дальше сам разберусь

Оплата в liqpay

Answer (score 0):

Думаю - никак.

Вы ломаете бизнес-логику.

Клиент делает заказ, оплачивает, заказ исполняется.

Если оплата не поступает, заказ отменяется.

Надо следить за временем и через разумный период перемещать заказ в неоплаченные.